# Support for Chat feature in Stack Overflow

Tags: support, status-completed, chat

I was feeling the need of a chat enabled service for discussions on Stack Overflow.
Don't you think, it should be implemented?

Comment: Belongs to meta. Also, http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: no. then ppl will start bugging others for help. it's voluntarily!
Should go to Meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Now http://chat.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is being worked on. See [here](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Please read the FAQ for more details: http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/faq