# Are there plans to add the "chat" feature to stackoverflow?

Tags: support, chat

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Support for Chat feature in Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61171/support-for-chat-feature-in-stack-overflow)
>   [Why doesn't Stack Overflow have a chatroom like chat.superuser.com/?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65094/why-doesnt-stack-overflow-have-a-chatroom-like-http-chat-superuser-com)

Are there plans to add the "chat" feature to stackoverflow?  If so when, and if not why?

Thanks!

Comment: @dmckee I don't think they're the same; that was "chat should exist", this is "chat exists on MSO and it should be on SO too"

Comment: @Michael: The *answer* is exactly the same: chat *is* coming to SO in time, but it'll be the last place because of the scaling issues. Same answer, so working differences aside, same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [blog post announcing SU chat](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/super-user-chat-now-available/):

> Although [**chat.superuser.com**](http://chat.superuser.com) is technically another public beta, we’re still on track for releasing chat network-wide in a few weeks. However, **stackoverflow.com will be the *last* site to get chat** because its immense volume presents the hardest challenge.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

6 to 8 Weeks.

Comment: Eventually all the sites will get it. However, before it hits the big site, it is being tested on all the other sites.

Comment: It depresses me that you posted the joke as the answer and the actual answer as a comment